# Checking GeoLite2 have IP Adress

Tags: php, database, laravel, geolite2

I use [this repository](https://github.com/danielme85/laravel-geoip2).

But, I don't know how to check if that data exists.

Help me.

All codes error.

```
Reader::connect()->city($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);
Reader::connect()->city($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"])->mostSpecificSubdivision->name;
Reader::connect()->city($request->ip());
Reader::connect()->city($request->ip())->mostSpecificSubdivision->name;
```

In the first place, an error has occurred at the time of the city function.

Comment: `$variable_name = $reader->city($ip)->jsonSerialize();` check  `$variable_name`

Comment: @A.ANoman "The address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is not in the database."

Comment: So where do you get ip_address??

Comment: This way : `$request->ip()`

Comment: This also gives an error.
`Reader::connect()->city($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);`

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: It's your local server or remote server?? Try this for example Reader::connect()->city("151.101.1.69");

Comment: You don't seem to understand what I want to hear.
I've been hearing how to get no error when the IP address doesn't exist in the database.
I can find my current Global IP address.

Answer (score 0):

check your ip exist use `isset` like below

```
if(isset($request->ip())){
    //Your code here
}
```

Comment: Do you understand?
I can get the IP address.
However, I want to do my own processing without returning an error when the IP address is not in the GeoLite2 database.

Comment: your answer in details where you follow this tutorial